# How many rows did I select in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

**Is there an easy way to count the amount of rows I selected in a sheet?**

I might be completely overlooking this but I don't see a counter or anything anywhere at all. The only counters I see is average, sum and cell count.

Comment: Are you looking to count any specific colored Rows or all Rows in Any Color?

Comment: @RajeshS I am looking to count all rows that I've highlighted regardless of their contents.

Comment: @MátéJuhász, ah, I mean select. I'll correct my question to reflect this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**My approach is little different, and I would like to suggest you, a VBA Macro using `Woksheet Selection Change Event` to count selected Rows, which actually automates the Count.**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
 
 Dim i As Long, lngAreas, lngRows As Long
    
    lngAreas = Selection.Areas.Count
    
    lngRows = 0
    
    For i = 1 To lngAreas
        lngRows = lngRows + Selection.Areas(i).Rows.Count
    Next i
    
    MsgBox "There are " & lngRows & " rows selected"
End Sub
```

**How it works:**

- Press **ALT+F11** to open VB Editor.
- *Copy & Paste* this Code & from **File
  Menu** click **Close & Return to
  Microsoft Excel**.
- Save the WB as Macro enabled *.xlsm.
- Select Cell/Rows, you get count through Message Box.

**N.B.**

*This Macro will Count Row/Rows, as soon you  select Row/Rows, using Mouse or Keyboard.*

Comment: Nice approach to generalise for multiple areas! Getting it automatically in a message box after EACH selection change can quickly get annoying.

Comment: Glad to help you @MMM ,,, keep asking ☺

Answer (score 1):

No. I don't think there would be anything built in.

However you can [create](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2013/12/06/add-run-vba-macro-excel/) a short macro and [assign a hotkey](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/automate-tasks-with-the-macro-recorder-974ef220-f716-4e01-b015-3ea70e64937b) to call it quickly:

```
Sub DisplayRowCount()
    MsgBox Selection.Rows.Count & " rows in the selection"
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: This will count Selected Rows whether Highlighted or not and the OP wants to count only Highlighted Rows !

Comment: Yeah @Máté Juhász ,, now I've edited my post and included Macro using Worksheet Selection Change Event, which automates the Count!!

Answer (score -1):

You do not have to select the rows you want to count across all the columns in the worksheet. Just select the rows you want to count in a single column and look at the bottom right corner of the status bar, you will see COUNT displayed.

Comment: COUNT only counts cells, and only those with a value. Selecting 10 empty rows will not give a result, and merged cells that span multiple rows are counted as one.

Comment: It only count cells because you select the rows across more than one column. If it’s the number of rows selected you want to get, just select all the rows you want to count with a single column and look at the bottom right for the COUNT.